# String comparison in if statement not working

Tags: c

I am new in C programming. Can you please advise, what's wrong with my code? It looks like the `if` statement is not working, and instead it's jumping and printing the `else` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char profession;

    printf("what is your profession? \n");
    scanf(" %s", profession);

    if(profession==“QA”)
    {
        printf(“Go and Test\n“);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Do whatever you want");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope - cannot compare null-terminated char arrays like that.  It's also a multi-dup.

Comment: I am still confused. like where i should make changes?

Comment: You have multiple errors which show some missconception. Your compiler should warn already (if not, enable warnings). Please read a C book about pointers, arrays and string literals (and the rest).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't compare strings like that in C. use `strcmp` or `strncmp` instead.

Secondly, in your code, `profession` is a `char`, and you want to put a string (several chars) in it. It won't work. You can create a `char *` (pointer on a `char`) (without forgetting to `malloc()` it) or a `char []` (a char array).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, strings in C are array of characters, so you have to declare profession as a pointer, pointing to an array of characters. So that statement will look like this `char* profession`, secondly, you have to use a method called `strcmp(char* a, char* b)` that accepts two char pointers. This will return 0 if they are equal. I will include the answer, but I assume there are better ways of writing this code.

```
int main() {

    char* profession;
    char* compare = "QA";
    printf("What is your profession?\n");

    scanf(" %s", profession);

    if(strcmp(profession, compare) == 0) {
            printf("Go and Test\n");
    } else {
            printf("Do whatever you want");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and solution as well